# Why does the semantics of pair differ in different usage scenarios?

Tags: between, dolphindb, key-pair

For example, `for(r in 1:6){print r}` returns “1, 2, 3, 4, 5“, excluding the right boundary. However, `6 between 1:6` returns true, meaning that “6“is included in the pair. Are the two contradictory?

Answer (score 0):

When used as a header specifying the iteration in loop statements, `pair` excludes the right boundary, which is similar to the `range` function in Python. However, when used in functions and SQL statements with the `between` operator, `pair` includes both boundaries.